# USB Full-Speed driver's effect on transfer speed

Tags: usb, serial, driver, linux

I am experiencing problems with USB communications which seems driver related. My setup involves an embedded device set up as a virtual com port (CDC/ACM) with which I communicate over USB. The problem is that the data rates are very slow on a certain computer. I have tested the embedded device on various Linux computers and found the problem to be specific to that pc (the one that matters).

From the output of `dmesg` the only noticeable difference is the driver being loaded on the different computers. The troublesome pc uses uhci-hcd, whereas others use either ehci-hcd or xhci-hcd. With ehci being available on the slow pc, I tried to dictate which driver is loaded but that seems easier said than done on Linux. Others have suggested blacklisting uhci-hcd, but `rmmod` returns with an error saying the 'module is built-in'.

The OS on the pc was upgraded from a 32-bit Ubuntu 12 to Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit (processor is 64 bit). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_controller_interface_(USB,_Firewire)#Universal_Host_Controller_Interface) mentions that uhci only supports 32-bit memory addressing, requiring an expensive bounce buffer to work with a 64-bit OS. Could this be the reason for the slow data rates?

The embedded processor ([Infineon XMC4400](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/xmc4400_rm_v1.5_2014_04.pdf?fileId=db3a30433afc7e3e013b3c46756b5c41)) supports full speed (12 Mbps) transfers which I understand corresponds to USB 1.0. Am I correct in assuming that certain drivers for USB 1 outperform others?

I am a bit of a hardware noob and would appreciate any advice in aid of a solution or comprehension of the problem. Should I attempt to force certain drivers for the device, and if so, how? Should I revert to a 32-bit OS, or am I maybe limited by the hardware?

The motherboard on the pc is a Versalogic Mamba EBX-37.

Comment: Why do you mention the upgrade? And why didn't you upgrade to some current kernel version?

Comment: I wondered whether the 64-bit OS might be causing problems with the uhci-hcd driver. The kernel has been upgraded to version 3.13.0-86-generic.

Comment: Performance depends on the details of the machine; you have to test this yourself. And "current" does not mean "over two years old".

Comment: Originally apt-get dist-upgrade wouldn't take it further than 3.13.0-86. I have now upgraded it to version 3.19.0-59-generic. Some of the other computers where I have tested successfully have kernels older than this.

Answer (score 1):

Seems as though my suspicion regarding the driver was correct. When the device is connected through a USB 2.0 hub, the ehci driver gets loaded and transfer speed increases drastically. Reverting to a 32-bit OS had no effect on the performance.